# Is there a way to automatically turn on MacBook Pros when power is plugged in for 2015 and lower models?

Tags: boot, macbook, automation

I would like to automatically have my 2015 MacBook Pro start up when external power is provided.

The reason is so I don't have to get up to press the button on my Mac and I can just have my Google Voice assistant to power it from the a smart plug and the MacBook boots up automatically.

2016 MacBook Pro models and up can do this but only if the screen lid is open. I want to be able to do the same thing with my 2015 MacBook Pro model but with the option to do it with the lid closed *or* opened.

For the option being closed is for so it will just show up on my external monitor screens without using the extra power to drive the CPU and GPU on my MacBook screen. Is there a script for this model or any one of them?

The 2015 MacBook Pro doesn’t have this feature but the 2016 MacBook Pro and up do when you plug in the power adapter, I figured its just a software thing.

Comment: Good question but it is probably an NVRAM setting. For example there are NVRAM settings to prevent MacBooks (2016 an newer) from starting up when the lid is open [as explained here](https://osxdaily.com/2017/01/19/disable-boot-on-open-lid-macbook-pro/). So your desire is essentially something like a “headless” MacBook running in something like “server mode” with the exception being you want an external monitor to be driven.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From the link you sent i found out that the following commands enables autoboot for newer MacBook pro 2016 and up, but for older MacBook won't work. i tried the command on my 2015 model, but it didnt start up after i plugged in power. Is this feature only for newer macs 2016 and up and can't be done with older macs through terminal or script or creating a custom app, like how GitHub people be doing? reason i want this is because i have voice command from google home to turn on office. the lights turn on my but my MacBook doesn't.